# Startup time in Solaris server using shell script

Tags: unix, shell, scripting, solaris

How to find the start up time of a Solaris 5.1 server using a shell script,need to know how much time it took to be on running state?I need to know how much time it took to come to running mode from starting mode?

Comment: Do you want to know when it started or how long it takes to start?

Comment: Also, wich version of Solaris? 10? 9?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such thing as Solaris 5.1, I guess you mean Solaris 10 a.k.a. SunOS 5.10.

Anyway, here is a way to know when the system last booted

```
last reboot | head -1
```

and here is an alternative, assuming CPUs weren't taken off and on later:

```
psrinfo
```

Answer (score 0):

one of the command you can try is uptime.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to find the boot-up time (which is not entirely accurate, assumes you're doing a complete reboot with no pause, and ignores hardware bootstrapping time, but does the job) is to simply inspect the logs and get the timecode where the system enters whichever state you're worried about, and subtract the timecode of the last 'halting' state